# Logging properties of Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

I'm starting on a project using Node.js, and I'm running into some issues with it's logging. I'm completely new to Node.js, but my understanding is that using console.log([data]) should print out the value of [data] to the server console.

I see this occurring how I expect in several places in this project, but when I try to add additional logging, nothing is prompted out to the console window.
I've noticed that all of the files where logging is working are under a specific folder, while the bulk of the code is under another.

Does anybody know what might be the cause of these not to print out into the console? I've also tried console.error([data]) and console.warning([data]) to see if it might be due to an error but that also didn't work.

Comment: The only reasons I know of that `console.log(data)` would not output anything are if that code is never actually being called (perhaps because of an exception beforehand).

Comment: That was what I thought initially, but if I put an alert immediately after the logging which displays as expected.

Comment: Then show us the specific code and the context around it that is not showing anything in the console.  Questions about code should nearly ALWAYS include the actual code you're asking about.  I'm also wondering how you put an alert into a node.js block of code.  Something sounds suspicious there. alert is a browser thing, not a node.js thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having your actual code, this is just a guess:

The files where the logging is working are the Javascript files for the server. The "bulk" of the code may be the client code (I guess so because you're saying in the comments of your post that you inserted a working `alert`, which is a browser thing), so your logs go to the browser not to the server.

Comment: I think you're right. It looks like it has something to do with the middleware. The application is using Express - `app.use(express.static(global.app_root_dir + "/public"));` All of the files in the /public directory seem to be ran on the client side, I looked at the brower's console and see the output.